# Edit BibTeX items appearance to add line break

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I'm using BibTeX with a style called *"hispa-annote"* ([source file](https://code.google.com/p/oflute/source/browse/doc/memoria/hispa-annote.bst)), and `@Misc` items (that I use to link to websites) currently look like this:

[image]

I'd like to have the title in one line and the URL in the following line, not in the same. How can I do it? I've tried editing the `.bst` file but I don't understand any of it.

The code for any of the entries is very simple:

```
@Misc{open-sans,
title = {Open Sans},
howpublished = {\url{http://opensans.com/}}
}
```

Comment: Please post the source code for some of the entries.

Comment: @Mico just added an example.

Comment: Please add an MWE which reproduces this behaviour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hack of the bst file [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=21554#p72435)

```
Add a line to FUNCTION {output.bibitem} in the file yourbib.bst

(...)
"}" write$
newline$
"\hspace{0em}\\"  % CHANGED LINE
before.all 'output.state :=
}
```